# Position a view with myView.frame

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, frame

I have done a simple code:

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)
```

in viewDidLoad and it is working well as expected.

But after I link this view from a table view and embed it into a navigation controller, it doesn't work.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
<targetView>.autoresizesSubviews = false;
```